Polars: Convert duration to integer number of hours/minutes/seconds
I want to convert a duration to integer number of hour (or minute or seconds). I though the .dt namespace would work the same as for the datetimes, but I get an error instead.
This example
from datetime import datetime
import polars as pl
pl.__version__

dx = pl.DataFrame({'dt1': datetime(2024, 1, 12, 13, 45)})
dx.select((pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.hour())

gives the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidOperationError                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 2
      1 dx = pl.DataFrame({'dt1': datetime(2024, 1, 12, 13, 45)})
----> 2 dx.select((pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.hour())

File ~/src/poste/sda-poste-logistics/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/dataframe/frame.py:8461, in DataFrame.select(self, *exprs, **named_exprs)
   8361 def select(
   8362     self, *exprs: IntoExpr | Iterable[IntoExpr], **named_exprs: IntoExpr
   8363 ) -> DataFrame:
   8364     """
   8365     Select columns from this DataFrame.
   8366 
   (...)
   8459     └───────────┘
   8460     """
-> 8461     return self.lazy().select(*exprs, **named_exprs).collect(_eager=True)

File ~/src/poste/sda-poste-logistics/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py:1967, in LazyFrame.collect(self, type_coercion, predicate_pushdown, projection_pushdown, simplify_expression, slice_pushdown, comm_subplan_elim, comm_subexpr_elim, cluster_with_columns, no_optimization, streaming, background, _eager, **_kwargs)
   1964 # Only for testing purposes atm.
   1965 callback = _kwargs.get("post_opt_callback")
-> 1967 return wrap_df(ldf.collect(callback))

InvalidOperationError: `hour` operation not supported for dtype `duration[μs]`

on both polars 0.20.31 and 1.0.0-a1.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

After the subtraction, you don't have a date anymore but a timedelta, you should use dt.total_seconds:
dx.select((pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.total_seconds())

Output:
┌───────┐
│ dt1   │
│ ---   │
│ i64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 49500 │
└───────┘

Or, as total_hours / fractional hours:
dx.select((pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.total_hours())

┌─────┐
│ dt1 │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 13  │
└─────┘

dx.select((pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.total_seconds()/3600)

┌───────┐
│ dt1   │
│ ---   │
│ f64   │
╞═══════╡
│ 13.75 │
└───────┘


If you want the integer number of hours in the time delta, use total_hours() not hour().  The hour() call is for timestamps.
dx = pl.DataFrame({'dt1': dt.datetime(2024, 1, 12, 13, 45)})
dx.select(
    (pl.col('dt1') - pl.col('dt1').dt.date()).dt.total_hours()
)

shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ dt1 │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 13  │
└─────┘


hours is deprecated ;)

Copied the wrong chunk of code.  Thanks.
